# sending data from js over wire to the controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Inside js function I'm creating javascript object which I then send to the mvc controller using ajax

```
var ab = { id: 100, name: "abc" }
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/home/dosomething",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(ab),
    success: function (result) {
        $("#myDiv").html(result);
        $("#showModal").modal("show");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error!");
    }
});
```

on server side I have

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(string ab) 
{
    ... ab is always null
}
```

I'm guessing that I should using some other data type as expected in controller method instead of string?

Comment: server side take a model as a parameter.

Comment: your are posting data, but on controller function you are using it as params. tries to post this as a param or get post values.

Comment: Your method needs to be `DoSomething(int id, string name)` since those are the names your sending (note also it can be just `data: ab,` and remove the `content Type: "application/json",` option)

Comment: If you tell MVC your sending json it will automatically try and build the parameters. You don't need to parse the json (i.e. get a string and then turn this into an object). MVC does this for you. Do what @StephenMuecke says

Comment: @StephenMuecke it's ok for this small number of parameters, but I actually have more then 20 properties, so I would rather pass a serializable object.

Comment: Not sure what you mean - why in the world would you want to pass a string and then have to deserialize it when this is all handled out of the box by the framework. If you have a model, then just make the method `DoSomething(MyModel model)` and all the properties will be bound.

Comment: @Stephen, ok, now it's clear

Comment: @psyLogic, That's for web API (at least the `[FromBody]` bit)

Comment: @StephenMuecke oh okay, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use id and name in your action method

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult DoSomething(int id, string name) 
 {
    //code
 }
```

Comment: could you pls accept it. this is coz this answer will be moved to the top and this will be helpful for other users without scrolling and searching the right answer. Now, if you see, users need to scroll to see the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

### JS:

```
var ab = { Id: 100, Name: "abc" }
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/home/dosomething",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ ab: ab }),
        success: function (result) {
            $("#myDiv").html(result);
            $("#showModal").modal("show");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error!");
        }
    });
```

### Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething(YourClass ab) 
{
  . . .
}
```

### Model:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a class of the JSON object, peg it as Serializable

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeClass
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller, you can now accept this as:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoSomething([FromBody] SomeClass someclass){
  // code
}
```

Comment: Remove the `[FromBody]` attribute - that's for web API

Answer (score 0):

```
var ab = { id: 100, name: "abc" }
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/home/dosomething",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    // what if you pass data like this
    data: JSON.stringify({ab:ab}),
    success: function (result) {
        $("#myDiv").html(result);
        $("#showModal").modal("show");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send  { id: 100, name: "abc" } as a string to the controller you need to change the data in ajax call to

> data: JSON.stringify({ab:ab}),

if you want to send id and name as separate paramamters change your controller to

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(string id, string name) 
{

}
```

and your ajax call data to

```
data: '{ "id":" 100 ","name":"abc" }',
```